# Unable to save the uploaded file into specific directory

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework-2.0

I want to upload files and save them into specific directory.And i am new to files concept.When i uploading files from my page they are saved in another directory(C:\Users\ROOTCP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\multipartBody989135345617811478asTemporaryFile) and not in specified directory.I am unable to set it.Please help me in finding a solution.For all help thanks in advance.

```
  public static Result uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() throws Exception {

    Logger.info("@C HoForms -->> uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() -->> ");
    final String  basePath = System.getenv("INVOICE_HOME");

    play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body()
            .asMultipartFormData(); // get Form Body

    StringBuffer fileNameString = new StringBuffer(); // to save file path
                                                        // in DB
    String formType = body.asFormUrlEncoded().get("formType")[0];// get formType from select Box
    FilePart upFile = body.getFile("hoFiles");//get the file details
    String fileName = upFile.getFilename();//get the file name
    String contentType = upFile.getContentType(); 
    File file = upFile.getFile();

    //fileName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(fileName, ".");

    // path to Upload Files
    File ftemp= new File(basePath +"HeadOfficeForms\\"+formType+"");

    //File ftemp = new File(basePath + "//HeadOfficeForms//" + formType); 
    File f1 = new File(ftemp.getAbsolutePath());// play

    ftemp.mkdirs();
     file.setWritable(true);
     file.setReadable(true);
     f1.setWritable(true);
     f1.setReadable(true);
     //HoForm.create(fileName, new Date(), formType); 

    Logger.info("@C HoForms -->> uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() <<-- Redirecting to Upload Page for Head Office");
    return redirect(routes.HoForms.showHoFormUploadPage());
}

}
```

I really confused why the uploaded file is saved in this(C:\Users\ROOTCP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\multipartBody989135345617811478asTemporaryFile) path.

Comment: What is value of `INVOICE_HOME`?

Comment: value of basepath is:D:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

`File file = upFile.getFile();` is the temporary File you're getting through the form input. All you've got to do is move this file to your desired location by doing something like this: `file.renameTo(ftemp)`.

Your problem in your code is that you're creating a bunch of files in memory `ftemp` and `f1`, but you never do anything with them (like writing them to the disk).

Also, I recommend you to clean up your code. A lot of it does nothing (aforementioned `f1`, also the block where you're doing the `setWritable`'s). This will make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: There are few issues, here as well. If save path is not local(say network drive, or EBS drive in AWS), `file.renameTo` will fail

Answer (score 0):

I believe when the file is uploaded, it is stored in the system temporary folder as the name you've provided.  It's up to you to copy that file to a name and location that you prefer.  In your code you are creating the File object f1 which appears to be the location you want the file to end up in.

You need to do a file copy to copy the file from the temporary folder to the folder you want.  Probably the easiest way is using the apache commons FileUtils class.

```
File fileDest = new File(f1, "myDestFileName.txt");
try {
  FileUtils.copyFile(ftemp, fileDest);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I really confuse where i have to put?can u please explain clearly.